# SQL Query to find the result as follows where in column a attribute is mapped to only blue, if its mapped to other then skip column a

Tags: sql

I have a Temp Table with columns a and b as follows

TEMP Table

```
   A        B
    abc     yellow
    abc     blue
    abc     orange
    def     blue
```

Result

```
A       B
def     blue
```

I want to fetch record from column a only when record from column a is mapped to blue and not any other colour

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here;  please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a windowed conditional count

```sql
SELECT
  t.*
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.B <> 'blue' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.A) AS count_not_blue
  FROM TEMP t
) t
WHERE t.count_not_blue = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get all pairs of *A*, *B* where *B* equals 'blue'. Next, join these pairs with your table. Finally, group the resulting dataset and select the entries that occur exactly once :

```
SELECT t.A, MAX(t.B) AS B
FROM TEMP t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT A, B
  FROM TEMP
  WHERE B = 'blue'
) AS s on s.A = t.A
GROUP BY t.A
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

This also can be done using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses without a self join :

```
SELECT t.A, MAX(t.B) AS B
FROM TEMP t
GROUP BY t.A
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.B = 'blue' THEN 1 END) = 1 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.B <> 'blue' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

[Demo on sql server here](https://dbfiddle.uk/esXOy7g9)

Comment: There are ways to achieve this *without* a self join.

Comment: @selvazi Thank you selvazi. It has been really helpful. :)

Comment: @ThomA Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I've added another solution that doesn't require a self-join.